# Tab or auto completion of command while editing a .tex file

Tags: latex, text-editing

Seeing if there is a way for auto or tab complete specifically while editing a .tex file.  For example

\text....   (tab or autocomplete) in some editors will allow you to quickly choose from '\textbf' '\textit' '\textregistered' etc.

Or similarly '\begin{'

I have tried using 'M-TAB' but this does not seem to be working for me.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What environment are you using? AUCTeX offers some completion commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Completion

Comment: how would I know if I am using AUCTeX? I suspect by my asking I am likely not.

Comment: I don't think it's installed by default. Installation instructions (and more documentation) can be found at https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/. I can recommend installing it, as it has a lot of features that help in writing LaTeX.